# How to perform Language translation on Single Page App with Angularjs and Laravel

Tags: angularjs, api, laravel

I have been thinking implementing translation for my app and I have the following idea

1. Make the English and My language [Amharic] mirror jsons and render English if selected. Just configuration Json file from the server that gets called once app routed
2. Make all in one API to get the json once and persist

will it be a good idea,How is this implemented on real world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need to implement it yourself. `angular-translate` is an excellent module, here you can take a look at it: https://angular-translate.github.io/ .It covers everything you need.

It is plenty of features and some of them are:

- Flexibility
- Pluralization
- Directive
- Filter
- Service
- Asynchronous loading

Keep in mind that this module has been there for a long time and many people use it. You can solve everything you need and there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Hey buddy that is exactly How i was going to implement that, Just two arrays swapping. Is there any feature that make me use that module